# How to do HTML array input with like this?

Tags: php, html, input

I have a laravel code that loop and this is the sample inputs

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $question['question'] }}" name="custom_form[question][{{ $question['name'] }}]" />
<input type="text" name="custom_form[answer][{{ $question['name'] }}]" />
```

and it result like this

[image]

any idea how to do like this result?

```
Array
(
    (
        [immigration_status] => Array
                    (
                        [question]  => What is your current Immigration status?
                        [answer]    => Naturalized Citizen
                    )
        [green_card] => Array
                    (
                        [question]  => Do you have a Green Card?
                        [answer]    => Yes
                    )
        ....
    )

)
```

if there is no like this on `<input>`, how to do this on foreach loop to result like this?

> What is your current Immigration status? Naturalized Citizen
>       Do you have a Green Card? Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just `foreach` over one array you have since the keys match for both questions and answers. You can then reference the key of the other array to get the current value

```
foreach($_POST['custom_form']['question'] as $key => $question) {
     echo htmlentities($question . ' ' . $_POST['custom_form']['answer'][$key]) . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If can be assumed that all fields always exist, this should work:

```
$transposed = [];
foreach($arr['question'] as $key => $value) {
    $transposed[$key] = array('question' => $value, 'answer' => $arr['answer'][$key]);
}
```

If you can't however, you need to do validity checking:

```
$transposed = [];
foreach($arr['question'] as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $arr['answer'])) {
        $transposed[$key] = array(
            'question' => $value,
            'answer'   => $arr['answer'][$key]
        );
    }
}
```